# Parsing array of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, hash, rubygems

Here is an example hash (maximum 10 per query)

```
parsed_response = [{"id"=>3, "pic"=>"/images/icons/market.png", "url"=>"https://angel.co/mobile-4", "name"=>"Mobile", "type"=>"MarketTag"}, {"id"=>12, "pic"=>"/images/icons/market.png", "url"=>"https://angel.co/enterprise-software", "name"=>"Enterprise Software", "type"=>"MarketTag"}, {"id"=>10, "pic"=>"/images/icons/market.png", "url"=>"https://angel.co/saas", "name"=>"SaaS", "type"=>"MarketTag"}, {"id"=>841, "pic"=>"/images/icons/market.png", "url"=>"https://angel.co/software", "name"=>"Software", "type"=>"MarketTag"}, {"id"=>263, "pic"=>"/images/icons/market.png", "url"=>"https://angel.co/restaurants-2", "name"=>"Restaurants", "type"=>"MarketTag"}, {"id"=>376, "pic"=>"/images/icons/market.png", "url"=>"https://angel.co/productivity-software", "name"=>"Productivity Software", "type"=>"MarketTag"}, {"id"=>942, "pic"=>"/images/icons/market.png", "url"=>"https://angel.co/embedded-hardware-and-software", "name"=>"Embedded Hardware and Software", "type"=>"MarketTag"}, {"id"=>291, "pic"=>"/images/icons/market.png", "url"=>"https://angel.co/meeting-software", "name"=>"Meeting Software", "type"=>"MarketTag"}, {"id"=>13764, "pic"=>"/images/icons/market.png", "url"=>"https://angel.co/hardware-software", "name"=>"Hardware + Software", "type"=>"MarketTag"}, {"id"=>2983, "pic"=>"/images/icons/market.png", "url"=>"https://angel.co/software-compliance", "name"=>"Software Compliance", "type"=>"MarketTag"}]
```

I've tried many methods inside of the gem I've been creating.

The first method was to create a special class and map each array element to that class:

```
class IDSearch
  attr_accessor :id, :thumbnail, :url, :name, :type
  def initialize(the_hash)
    @id   = the_hash['id']
    @url  = the_hash['url']
    @pic  = the_hash['pic']
    @name = the_hash['name']
    @type = the_hash['type']
  end
end
```

I'll list them according to attempt:

```
Attempt 1:
IDSearch.new(parsed_response)

Attempt 2:
parsed_response.map {|t| IDSearch.new(t)}

Attempt 3:
parsed_response.each do |hsh|
SimpleAngel::IDSearch.new(hsh)
end

Attempt 4:
10.times do |i|
  instance_variable_set "@response_#{i}", parsed_response[i]        
end

Attempt 5 (getting desperate)
@response0 = parsed_response[0]
@response1 = parsed_response[1]
@response2 = parsed_response[2]
@response3 = parsed_response[3]
@response4 = parsed_response[4]
@response5 = parsed_response[5]
@response6 = parsed_response[6]
@response7 = parsed_response[7]
@response8 = parsed_response[8]
@response9 = parsed_response[9]

Attempt6: (this time inside of a rails controller)

search_object = SimpleAngel::Search.new
responses = search_object.id_search(params[:query], params[:type])
responses.each_with_index do |response, i|
  u      = Idquery.new
  u.name = response[i]['name']
  u.id   = response[i]['id']
  u.url  = response[i]['url']
  u.type = response[i]['type']
  u.pic  = response[i]['pic']
  u.save
end
```

None of these methods has produced a predictable, coherent, workable response.

More than an actual solution, I'm looking for a clue as to how my thinking has been flawed.

Comment: Attempt 2 seems to work fine for me. What problems do you have exactly? BTW: the `attr_accessor` should probably be called `pic` too, not `thumbnail`.

Comment: Indeed, snippet 2 works. Can we see the error for that case?

Comment: The error was too much rum during testing. Attempt 2 was correct. If you guys hadn't told me I might have never figured that out out of frustration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Attempt1 you are expecting a hash in the `IDSearch.new` and actually passing an array.
If you instead do:

```
parsed_response.each {|hash| p IDSearch.new(hash)}
```

it works just fine.

```
@id=3, @url="https://angel.co/mobile-4", @pic="/images/icons/market.png", @name="Mobile", @type="MarketTag"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'ostruct'
parsed_response.map {|resp| OpenStruct.new(resp)}
```

Removes the need for a specific class.

Comment: The commenters were correct, attempt 2 was right. But thanks for teaching me something new.

Comment: Returned error: "NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for #<SimpleAngel::IDSearch:0x000etc>